# 503 Service Unavailable when trying to push data to Mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, azure, iis

I am running into a worrying problem with my Mongodb server. 
The system I've built has an android app which sends records to an azure virtual machine hosting an instance of Mongodb to be inserted through API calls. Everything was working fine up until today, records were being inserted and could be pulled quickly. The database is small at this point, only 6gb.

However today, every 3rd or 4th request for data or records being sent off is rejected with a 503 Service Unavailable response or takes a really long time to return. I've checked the server's memory usage and it is fairly high, about 6.3gb of RAM used out of the 7gb available. Could Mongo be rejecting requests due to running out of memory or are the operations timing out? If so is there a solution to this other than increasing the RAM available to the virtual machine?

Or could IIS be rejecting the requests due to Mongo taking up too much memory?

Edit: The environment is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter VM, with Mongo and my IIS running on the same machine.

Answer (score -1):

Where is your mongod instance running? GNU/Linux or Azure stuff / Windows server?

503 HTTP error means your web server is overloaded.

MongoDB will try to use as much RAM as it can for Cache, so 99% of RAM usage is normal if it is in 'cached' state.

You need to provide more info about your setup, but my wild guess is that your ISS is causing issues.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.